# Getting 403 on [secret/application] not resolvable Spring Vault configuration

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I configured my spring app to connect to Vault and when the app starts, I'm getting unnecessary call on path `[secret/application]`. My policy looks like,

```
path "secret/data/my-app" {
    capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

If I put `path "secret/application"` it's gone away. But I don't need that unnecessary policy in my policies. Is there a possible way to fix this. My bootstrap config looks like,

```
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://localhost:8200/
spring.application.name=my-app
spring.cloud.vault.token=token_value
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what spring-cloud-vault version you use, but I think you can find resolution here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/566.

Rename `spring.application.name` to `spring.application-name` or upgrade spring-cloud version to 2020.0.1